# Can a friend upload files to my UbuntuOne folder?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I understand that it is possible to share folders in UbuntuOne, and to give friends the privilege of downloading or modifying files. I would like to know, is it possible for a friend to upload a file into my folder? For example, I would like to invite a client to upload a video file to a folder I have shared with her, so that I may work on that file.

Thanks, 
Mercedes

Answer (score 2):

Yes. When sharing a folder to someone, you have the option of granting them permission to write to that folder. If you've already shared the folder without write access to that person, you may need to re-share it to them again, and select to allow write access.

Also note, any files the other person puts in your folder, will count toward your storage quota. If the file you want her to upload to you through Ubuntu One is larger than you're remaining available space, she won't be able to upload it until you either make space by deleting files you may no longer need, or purchase more storage space.